# Getting data from a promise of a promise along with other data (promise.all)

Tags: javascript, protractor

So I have a handful of promises that need to be resolved so I can get at the data.  Of course, I have the handy `promise.all()` available to me.  Unfortunately, one of those promises returns another array of promises.  Is it possible to get at those array of promises?

For example:

```
var result = {};
let pName = getName(); // returns promise<string>
let pAge = getAge(); // returns promise<string>
let pSchools = getSchools; // returns promise<Array<promise<string>>>

return promise.all([pName, pAge, pSchool]).then(function(res) {
   result["name"] = res[0];
   result["age"] = res[1];
   result["schools"] = [];

   // This next section I don't think will work because it doesn't resolve "in time".
   res[2].map(function(school) {
       school().then(theSchool => result["schools"].push(theSchool))
   }); 
   return result;
});  // returns promise<{
     //     "name": "string",
     //     "age": "string",
     //     "schools": [string1, ..., stringN]
     //  }>
```

Has anyone had to do something like this? How did you work it?

Comment: I'll give that a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the results from the inner Promise which resolves the schools :

```
return promise.all([pName, pAge, pSchool]).then(function(res) {
  return promise.all(res[2].map(school => school()))
      .then(schools => {
          result["name"] = res[0];
          result["age"] = res[1];
          result["schools"] = schools;
          return result;
      });
   }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As `getSchools` returns promise of Array of promise of string, so you need to spread the array of `pSchool` inside the `promise.all` as follow:

```
  return promise.all([pName, pAge, ...pSchool]).then(function(res) {
    result["name"] = res[0];
    result["age"] = res[1];
    result["schools"] = res.splice(0,2);

    return result;
});
```